# Phpmailer - smtp error: failed to connect to server: connection refused (111)

Tags: php, phpmailer

I have a server on AWS hosting 20 clients apps. All of this are using the same php code with his own email config. But one, can't send emails.
The message I receive from phpmailer debug is:

**smtp error: failed to connect to server: connection refused (111)**

I try a lot of changes but never works with this host email:

- We are using tls and port 587
- Telnet from my localhost to this mail host/port work fine (I can't use telnet/nmap, orr similar on server)
- With his email data (user/pass/server..) I can send email from my pc. But not on server
- The firewall on server is disabled
- The SMTP restrictions on WHM are disabled too
- If try to use port 25, I receive a 110 timeout.

On my computer everything works perfectly, but the server must block the connection in some way, but I can't find what it can be.
Is it possible that it is the email host that is blocking the connection only from the server?

Code:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer(); 
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->setFrom($from, 'Text');
$mail->Subject      = 'text'
$mail->Timeout      = 300;
$mail->SMTPSecure   = $secure; //tls
$mail->Host         = $host; 
$mail->Port         = $port; //587
$mail->Username     = $user;
$mail->Password     = $pass;
$mail->AddAddress($mailto);
$mail->Body = $message;
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->SMTPDebug = 4; 

$mail->IsHTML(true);

if($mail->Send()) {
}
```

Comment: Read what [the troubleshooting guide has to say about this](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting#smtp-error-could-not-connect-to-smtp-host). It will be outbound SMTP blocking by your hosting provider, and your local broadband provider isn't doing the same thing, which is why it works on your computer.

Comment: It was the first thing I looked at. But it is working fine with all clients. The only thing different is the destination host. And all of them (clients) are sending by tls/587. At this point, I understand that either my server is blocking the connection to this specific destination host, or the destination host is refusing it. But I can't find the reason.

Comment: "with all clients" – but those clients are not running on your server, so they have nothing to do with it. Your provider likely blocks all traffic on port 587, to any host.

Comment: Yes, all clients are on the same server. Controlled by the same WHM, each with a different CPanel/url/etc..

Comment: Ah ok. I misunderstood your configuration. I don’t think this has anything to do with PHPMailer as it sounds like it affects all outbound from that specific installation, not just PHP. You could try testing by temporarily using the troublesome settings on a client app that does work. That would narrow the possible causes.

Comment: I have tried with the data in another client and it also fails. I realized that I could execute Curl in the server terminal. "curl telnet://h0237.hostytec.com:587" works from my machine but not from the server. I suppose it will be my server that blocks it, but how can I see it?

Comment: You could enable logging in your firewall, though I find cpanel makes things like that unnecessarily difficult, to see whether it is a local firewall issue. Try traceroute to see how for your traffic is getting.